# How do I clamp __m128i signed integers into non-negative unsigned integers in SSE

Tags: c++, max, sse, clamp

I can't figure out how to convert 4 x 32 bit signed integers stored in a single __m128i into "unsigned" counterparts. The conversion should be done with value truncation, clamping negative numbers to 0 but leaving non-negative numbers unchanged.

E.g: -100 should turn into 0, while 100 should remain 100

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main()
{    
    alignas(16) uint32_t out32u[4];
    __m128i my = _mm_setr_epi32 (100, -200, 0, -500);
    <....missing code....>
    _mm_store_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i *>(out32u), my);
    printf("%u %u %u %u\n", out32u[0], out32u[1], out32u[2], out32u[3]);
}
```

So given the
`<....missing code....>` additions the result of the code above should become:

`100 0 0 0`

Comment: How about `_mm_max_epi32` with a (0, 0, 0, 0) vector?

Comment: Store the values in signed int array, then iteratively check and zero out the negatives in the array.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good option. How did I not figure it out myself.... Was looking for some bit-wise magic instead.

Comment: If you don't have SSE4.1 you could do `a & ~ (a >> 31)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SSE4.1 [`_mm_max_epi32`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=595,5430,338,329,338,5430,3576,3576&text=_mm_max_epi32) as:

```
my = _mm_max_epi32(my, _mm_setzero_si128());
```

Or without that, @chtz's elegant `a & ~(a >> 31)` can be implemented using SSE2 as follows:

```
my = _mm_andnot_si128(_mm_srai_epi32(my, 31), my);
```

Replace `<....missing code....>` with the above line.

[Generated assembly for both methods](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4adPcG).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for `_mm_setzero_si128`, wasn't aware of it. But was pleasantly surprised that the generated assembly is the same https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bTGTdv

Comment: I was hoping it would fix GCC's braindead choice to copy `my` to xmm1, then xor-zero xmm0, but it doesn't.  Not as pleasant as I'd hoped.  But yeah, compilers know zeroing idioms, that's what they're for.  Just like scalar `return 0` will `xor eax,eax`.  You'd also get the same asm from `_mm_set1_epi32(0)`, or from `_mm_set_epi32(0,0,0,0)`.  `_mm_setzero_si128()` isn't magic in modern compilers; IDK if ancient compilers used to need help to use xor-zeroing, but they don't now.  It's only useful for the semantic meaning for human readers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yep, I noticed sub-optimal `gcc` register allocation in `g` and `h` too. I am tired of reporting [poor register allocation bugs to gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91796). On the other hand, quite surprisingly, for `f` `gcc` allocates registers better than `clang` does.

Comment: GCC's register allocator apparently is well-known to be bad at tiny functions, where it has to obey the calling convention's hard-register constraints for both input and output.  But it's usually not a problem inside larger functions.  (wasted mov instructions are sometimes present even in loops, though).  Clang is usually better, but does stumble sometimes, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes I heard that argument but in the absence of evidence I am not convinced that `gcc` allocating registers sub-optimally for small functions magically does better on larger ones. The former doesn't imply or cause the latter. `gcc` register allocation faults can ideally possibly cancel each other, or, in the worst case, compound.

Comment: I've heard this argument from GCC devs, not just people making up guesses to explain observations, so I'm more inclined to believe it.  (Although I haven't looked at the code myself to really understand the reasons.)  It makes some sense that the reg allocator has special code to handle specific hard-register requirements, so it's certainly plausible it does worse with that than when spilling/reloading for register pressure, or just chaining together sequences of operations and letting dead values die.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, the fact that `clang` often allocates registers better in small functions than `gcc` means that `gcc` does a worse job within the same constrains and negates the that "small function register constraint" or nebulous "specific hard-register requirements" argument. Both compilers obey the same ABI requirements. I may be wrong, but that's what it appears to me based on the above logic.

Comment: Nobody's saying it's impossible in general to do well!  Just that *GCC's* register allocation algorithm is sub-optimal for that case, moreso than for other cases.  (But as we can see, clang also has similar missed optimizations sometimes, even for functions that are trivially simple for humans.)  Keep in mind that compiler algorithms need to be fast even for large problem sizes, which often means they can't explore the full range of the problem space to find optimal solutions if there's no efficient-enough algorithm.  (Like O(n^2) might be ok, but not exponential.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I am only saying that gcc devs' argument lacks any supporting evidence and that's why I cannot trust it. Nothing prevents `gcc` register allocator from making different decisions based on function size that results in ideal register allocation.

Comment: I don't see your point at all.  I think you're countering some argument that it would be impossible to ever fix gcc, but that's not the argument GCC devs are making.  Just explaining that GCC's current code isn't great for this case.  (With the implication they think it's not important and don't plan to fix it - inline small funcs.)  If you look at asm for larger functions, there aren't wasted `mov` instructions all over the place, not to this degree.  So it certainly appears that it's just at ABI boundaries that it does worse.  (And probably around `asm` statements with hard-reg constraints.)

Comment: TL:DR: I don't see any reason not to take the word of GCC devs about the current state of GCC's internals, barring any concrete evidence that contradicts what they say.  Of course it could be improved by adding more special cases, if GCC devs would accept such a patch.